# Add execute button to Commerce POS modal?

Tags: commerce

I'm building a custom POS modal similar to the POS_Button_Modal_View -based ones that present a view. I wrote a modal that presents a page from a given callback:

```
class POS_Button_Modal_Page extends POS_Button_Modal {

  public function modalPage(CommercePOS $pos, $js) {
    $form_state = array(
      'title' => drupal_get_title(),
      'build_info' => array('args' => array($pos->getState()->getOrder())),
      'ajax' => $js,
      'pos' => $pos
    );

    if (!$js) {
      return drupal_build_form($this->config['page callback'], $form_state);
    }

    $output = ctools_modal_form_wrapper($this->config['page callback'], $form_state);

    return $output && !$form_state['executed'] ? $output : FALSE;

  }
...
```

The modal displays my page as intended, but I don't know how to build a submit button that works like the buttons in the POS-provided views.

The view in, eg. the SetUser POS modal uses the commerce_pos handler to render a button that executes the command:

```
class commerce_pos_handler_field_pos_command extends views_handler_field { ...
```

How can I build a submit button in my custom modal that executes my new command?

My command extends POS_Command with my custom implementation of execute()

```
class POSCommand_MyCommand extends POS_Command {

  function execute(CommercePOS $pos, $input = '') { ...
```

It seems like a POS_Button_Command should be created and rendered in the modal. But how does that get connected to my command?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of a regular "page" callback, implement the page as a form with an action (submit) button. When the form is submitted and validates, the modal will be released courtesy of the way `ctools_modal_form_wrapper()` works.

POS_Command was not the right way to think about the problem in this case. POS_Button_Command is better suited to a simple, pre-defined operation as in setting the order user from a list of users. I was trying to do a more complex operation in the modal, gather some data from form inputs, then run some commerce commands on the order.

Short answer: The `POS_Button_Modal_Page` class works for loading a custom modal page. Implement the page as a form, and do the execution code in the form_submit handler instead of using POS_Command.